# SQL To Find Records With Date Greater Than Matching Entry On Other Table

Tags: sql

Anyone able to advise on how i'm going wrong here?

Table FXD contains details of the date(FXDNRMVPD) and time(FXDNRMVPT) every transaction on a fund was carried out.

Table TEMP contains a single record for each fund with the date(FXOVALDTE) and time(FXOVALTME) of the MOST RECENT valid transaction.

```
FXD
FXDFUND   FXDFUNDT   FXDNRMVPD   FXDNRMVPT   TRN_ID

001       A          2000-12-01  13.00.00    Z12566
001       A          2000-12-25  13.00.00    Z12678
001       A          2001-02-23  14.30.00    Z12899
002       D          2011-03-14  17.00.00    Z13421
002      D          2012-03-18  15.00.00    Z13986

TEMP
FXOFUND  FXOFUNDT    FXOVALDTE   FXOVALTME
001      A           2000-12-25  13.00.00
002      D           2011-03-14  17.00.00
```

I am trying to find the TRN_ID of all FXO records where the transaction took place AFTER the last valid transaction date/time for that fund according to the data in TEMP(Basically, the funds in question are all closed but people carried on buying stock after the close date)

The Date/Time fields in both tables are defined as CHAR due to poor design.

So I want the FXD.TRN_ID where the DATE/TIME fields are greater than the corresponding date/time on TEMP but can't seem to get it to work.

Tried this which did not work

```
SELECT FXD.TRN_ID FROM UDEVAGLIB/FXD, UDEVAGLIB/AAA
   WHERE FXDFUND  = FXOFUND                        
     AND FXDFUNDT = FXOFUNDT                       
     AND (CONCAT(FXDNRMVPD,FXDNRMVPT))             
       > (CONCAT(FXOVALDTE,FXOVALTME))
```

Comment: `CONCAT` calls will cause you to skip any indices you have, might be worth writing longer code that can use indices by going for something more like ` AND (a.date > b.date OR a.date = b.date AND a.time > b.time)` despite it looking less efficient on first glance SQL Server should be able to use the indices on this to work out which rows need more work and which don't.

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: Are there any leading/trailing spaces in your CHAR fields containing the date and time? If they have a difference there (e.g., extra space in one but not in the other), that might explain why you're not matching the way you think you should be

Comment: Cheers Scragar, took your suggestion and that fixed it. It appears that my original query 'may' have been working but it was just taking forever to run so I thought it was extracting records incorrectly so seems it was the indices being ignored that made me think it was going wrong.